# Where can I find rules for Revolver Fanning?

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

Wikipedia definition of [Fanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanning_(firearms))

> Fanning is a revolver shooting technique in which one hand holds the trigger and the other hits the hammer repeatedly. This turns the cylinder and hits the firing pin, in that order, allowing for 'semi-automatic fire' of single action revolvers.

I imagine this is probably in a merit, or something, somewhere, does someone know where? I also suspect this has not yet been ported to 2.0 rules, but would appreciate knowing if it has.

Comment: As opposed to rules for Dakota Fanning.

Comment: Isn't it mechanically *impossible* to fan a contemporary double-action revolver? So unless the dude is some kind of Holtz-like Old West-style werewolf hunter... Um. Never mind. *Now* I'm on board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in **WoD: Armory** on page 53:

> A character must have Firearms 2 with a Revolvers Specialty to fan. She may expend three shots to fire a short autofire burst. If the revolver has at least six shots loaded, she may completely empty it to fire a medium autofire burst (see p. 160, the World of Darkness Rulebook). In either case, fanning raises the revolver’s Strength requirement by 1. A dramatic failure while fanning may result in the character snapping off the hammer or slapping the gun out of her own hand to land at an enemy’s feet.

Comment: It's worth noting that the *autofire* rules were updated.